# Force close after item click on listview

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I just want to open an activity on from an item on list view but I get a force close.
can you please help me solve this? 
here is my code.
below...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.lessons_1);

mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );

String[] planets = new String[] { "Audio", "Bluetooth", "Camera", "DRM",
                                  "Encryption", "External Storage", "Graphics",      "Input"};  
ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );

listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, planetList);
listAdapter.add( "Media" );
listAdapter.add( "Security" );
listAdapter.add( "Sensors" );
listAdapter.add( "Dalvik" );
listAdapter.add( "Power" );
listAdapter.add( "Kernel" );
mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );    

ListView lv = getListView();

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
  int position, long id) {

  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewAct.class);
  startActivity(i);

    }
});
 }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately i acnt post logcat.. my emulator is superb slow.. im using my tablet as my tester.. is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: use same listview instance for setting `setOnItemClickListener` which you are using for setting adapter for ListView . change `lv.setOnItemClickListener` to `mainListView` and also add logcat results with question to get more help from us

Comment: It doesn'te matter that you're testing on your tablet, just keep the device connected while you're testing and go to the DDMS to see what's happening during the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
ListView lv = getListView();
```

and change

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener
```

to

```
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener
```

and if your class is called Main use

```
Main.this
```

Instead of

```
getApplicationContext()
```

Comment: It works but you know how I can set on click activity on every list item? sorry sir im noob

Comment: It already is on every item. The position and id specifies the item.

Comment: yes sir but how can I call different activity on different item? what should I use?

Comment: if(position==1) //do this

Comment: I have tried but now it opens the two class. even in other item      mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
       int position, long id) {
      if(position==0);
      {
       Intent i = new Intent(Lessons1.this, ForthActivity.class);
       startActivity(i);
      }
      
      if(position==1);
       Intent i = new Intent(Lessons1.this, SecondActivity.class);
       startActivity(i);
     }

Comment: use brackets for the if statement

Answer (score 0):

Your intent is using getApplicationContext(), but should use your current Context, i.e. current Activity.